# Dialog window procedure as a member function of a class

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195653/), I'm trying to create a simple Win32 application, in which the window procedure/callback function of a dialog window is a member function of a class. My code looks like this:

H file:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
    public:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HWND hWnd;

    int APIENTRY WinMainProc(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WinProcWraper(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);
    LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);
    ATOM MyClassRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance); 
};
```

CPP file:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::WinProcWraper(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (WM_NCCREATE == message)
    {
        SetWindowLong (hWnd, GWL_USERDATA,  (long)((CREATESTRUCT*) lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        return TRUE;
    }

    return ((MyClass*) GetWindowLong (hWnd, GWL_USERDATA))->WinProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY MyClass::WinMainProc(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    MyClass.hInstance=hInstance;
    MyClass.MyClassRegisterClass(hInstance);

    //MY PROBLEM IS HERE: cannot convert parameter 4 to int
    HWND hWnd = CreateDialog(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN_DIALOG), 0, (DLGPROC)MyClass::WinProc);

    ShowWindow(hWnd,nCmdShow); 
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
    
        if (!IsWindow(hWnd) || !IsDialogMessage(hWnd,&msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return  static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    (...)
}
```

When calling `CreateDialog()`, I get the following error:

```
cannot convert from 'long (__stdcall MyClass::*)(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)'
                 to 'long (__stdcall          *)(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)'
```

How can I make the correct type conversion in this case?

Comment: You went through the trouble of creating a `static` wrapper (`WinProcWraper`) for your callback. Why are you not using it? (The answer to the question you linked to uses its wrapper function.)

Comment: FYI, `WM_NCCREATE` may not be the first message a window received, just the first one that gives you access to the `void*` given to `CreateWindow/Ex()` (which you are not even using)

Comment: How do I do this? I tried using this, like it is used in the post, but it does not work. My problem is that I am using CreateDialog instead of CreateWindowEx and I don't know how to pass the window procedure as the fourth parameter of the function.

Comment: @TylerD007 see the answer I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the error message.  You are trying to use a **non-static** class method, `WinProc()`, as your `CreateDialog()` callback.  That will not work.  You went to the trouble of implementing a `static` class method, `WinProcWraper()`, which calls `WinProc()`, but you are not actually using it.  You need to use `WinProcWraper()` as the actual window procedure for `CreateDialog()`.

Also, there is no need to type-cast `WinProcWraper` when passing it to `CreateDialog()`, if its signature is correct to begin with (which yours is not).

After fixing that, you still have other problems:

- the [other code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28491549/65863) you are modeling after was designed for a window procedure for `CreateWindow/Ex()`, but you are using `CreateDialog()` instead, which has different requirements.
- Since you are using `CreateDialog()` instead of `CreateWindow/Ex()`, `WinProcWraper()` and `WinProc()` need to return a `BOOL` instead of an `LRESULT`.  If an actual `LRESULT` value needs to be returned to the system, `WinProc()` will need to use `SetWindowLong(DWL_MSGRESULT)` for that purpose.
- `WinProcWraper()` is expecting to receive a `WM_NCCREATE` message to deliver it a `MyClass*` pointer, which it will then assign to the `HWND`. But, since you are using `CreateDialog()`, `WinProcWraper()` will not receive any `WM_(NC)CREATE` messages, it will receive a `WM_INITDIALOG` message instead. And even then, `CreateDialog()` does not allow you to pass any user-defined value to the window procedure, so you can't pass in the `MyClass*` pointer that `WinProcWraper()` requires.  You need to use `CreateDialogParam()` instead for that.
- `WM_INITDIALOG` may not be the first message a window receives, just the first message that can give you access to the `MyClass*` pointer that you pass to `CreateDialogParam()`.  `WinProcWraper()` needs to handle the possibility that it can receive messages before it has received access to the `MyClass*` pointer.
- You are using `SetWindowLong()`.  Your code will not work if it is ever compiled for 64bit.  Use `SetWindowLongPtr()` instead, even for 32bit code.

With that said, try this:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
public:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HWND hWnd;

    int APIENTRY WinMainProc(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
    BOOL CALLBACK WinProc(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    ATOM MyClassRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance); 

private:
    static BOOL CALLBACK WinProcWraper(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK MyClass::WinProcWraper(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MyClass *cls;

    if (WM_INITDIALOG == uMsg)
    {
        cls = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(lParam);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(cls));
    }
    else
        cls = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

    if (cls)
        return cls->WinProc(uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    return FALSE;
}

int APIENTRY MyClass::WinMainProc(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    MyClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    MyClass.MyClassRegisterClass(hInstance);

    HWND hWnd = CreateDialogParam(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN_DIALOG), NULL, MyClass::WinProcWraper, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
    if (!hWnd)
        return -1;

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow); 
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!IsWindow(hWnd) || !IsDialogMessage(hWnd, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

BOOL CALLBACK MyClass::WinProc(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...

    if (needed)
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_MSGRESULT, ...);

    return ...; // TRUE or FALSE as needed...
}
```

Comment: An alternative to passing a pointer to a class instance through the system is to use thread local storage. Starting with C++11 there's a [thread_local](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local) keyword making use of thread local storage convenient. One could either use it to temporarily store context data until it is attached to a window, or to keep a permanent lookup table. The benefits are that an implementation is resilient to message ordering changes, and clients get to see *all* messages from the very start.

Comment: @IInspectable true. And even before C++11, there is the [Win32 thread-local API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-local-storage) via `TlsAlloc()` and `Tls(Get|Set)Value()`, which can be used to accomplish the same thing.